# Whats wrong with this simple Layout?

Tags: android

Im trying to define a LinearLayout which contains another LinearLayout which should always be desplayed in the horizontal and vertical center. An ImageView should be placed always vertically centered on the right side of the parent Layout:

> ```
>                                  A                                           B
> ```

I defined it the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px">

     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="50px" android:paddingTop="5px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/footer_border" android:paddingRight="5px" android:paddingLeft="5px" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/libraryButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/library_button" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/bookButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/book_button" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="15px" android:paddingRight="15px"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/workspaceButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/workspace_button" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:id="@+id/loading">
     </ImageView>

     </LinearLayout>
```

But unfornatuley its not working... The LinearLayout (A) and the ImageView (B) is on the left side.... But i set gravity to center and right?? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity in LinearLayout with horizontal orientation will only work for top,
bottom and center_vertical value([here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c67710fbc971a9d4/f3011cc8dd13216f?lnk=gst&q=LinearLayout+gravity#f3011cc8dd13216f)).

I think the best way to achieve such a thing is to use a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:center_in_parent="true"
>
....
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/loading"
android:align_parent_right="true">
</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm sorry but i can't test it right now..I hope it is right..

Comment: I tested your layout but there are to errors:

ERROR No resource identifier found for attribute 'align_parent_right' in package 'android

and


ERROR No resource identifier found for attribute 'center_in_parent' in package 'android'

Comment: ah ok i found the syntax error in your code. i test it again.

Comment: thanks a lot your solution works. i added

android:layout_centerVertical="true"

to the ImageView and now its perfect

But this is really another nasty bug in android which costs some hours to detect like the ArrayList Bug in Android 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `android:layout_alignParentRight` parameter

```
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="right"
 android:id="@+id/loading"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</ImageView>
```

Tell me if that works...

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. still all layout views on the left side